# How to variable values comes from firestore database?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android

I'm using firestore database, this is my variables

```
  final firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  int lessonpoint1 = 0;
  int lessonpoint2 = 0;
```

I've created a metod to create these variables on startup

```
  create() async {
    try {
      await firebase.collection("Accounts").doc(_user.uid).set({
        "Adı Soyadı": _user.displayName,
        "Mail Adresi": _user.email,
        "lessonpoint1": lessonpoint1,
        "lessonpoint2": lessonpoint2,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

after I create it, I don't want the variables here to have a value of 0 here. I want to pull these values from firestore. How can I do that? I give the value 10 to the variable with Update, but when I want to access the variable, the value 0 at the global level comes.

Thank you,
have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly setting the value from the client you could either use a `Transaction` or `FieldValue.increment()`.

With a `Transaction` you would ensure that you always get the latest value from the database and update it on it.

With `FieldValue.increment()` it's very similar but much less syntax and you can work inly with simple increments.

If you for example want to increase the points on each visit by `10` you could write your code like this:

```
create() async {
    try {
      await firebase.collection("Accounts").doc(_user.uid).set({
        "Adı Soyadı": _user.displayName,
        "Mail Adresi": _user.email,
        "lessonpoint1": FieldValue.increment(10),
        "lessonpoint2": FieldValue.increment(10),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

If you are only interested how to get the data itself from firestore I would recommend to check out first the docu [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data).

You can read more about both the methods them [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#transactions).